# Find a smooth function $\eta:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ whose support is a disk.

Tags: analysis, analytic-functions, smooth-functions

This comes from the proof of the following lemma in Jost's *Compact Riemann Surfaces* (Lemma 2.3.3).

> **Lemma 2.3.3** Every compact Riemann surface $\Sigma$ admits a conformal Riemann metric.
>
> *proof.* ... For a disk $D\subset\mathbb C$ we choose a smooth function $\eta:\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$ with
> $$\eta>0\text{ on }D,\quad\eta=0\text{ on }\mathbb C\backslash D$$
> ...

**My questions:**

(1) Does "smooth" here mean "infinitely differentiable as a $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ function (just to make sure)?

(2) How to guarantee the existence of such functions?

For (2) I know such functions must be smooth but non-analytic. The only example I know is
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}e^{-1/x}&,&x>0\\0&,&x\leq0\end{array}\right.$$
But how to generalize this to an $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ function?

Comment: Replace $x$ by $\vert x\vert$.

Comment: You mean like $f(1-|x|)$ with $x\in\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: (1): yes. For (2), consider, say, the function $g(x)=f(1-|x|^2)$ for your $f$.

Comment: It seems I left out the square.

Comment: You're looking for a [bump function][1].  


  [1]: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=e^{-\frac 1 {1-x}}$ for $x<1$ and $0$  for $x \geq 1$  defines a smooth function which is positive on $(-\infty,1)$ and $0$ outside it. So $f(\|x\|^{2})$ is a smooth function on $\mathbb R^{2}$ which is positive for $\|x\|<1$ and $0$ elsewhere.  For any other disk in $\mathbb R^{2}$ use an appropriate affine transformation.

Answer (score 3):

Define$$\eta(z)=\begin{cases}e^{\frac1{\lvert z\rvert^2-1}}&\text{ if }\lvert z\rvert<1\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: is it smooth at $0$?

Comment: *Now* it is smooth.